# gridExport2.WriteXlsxToResponse("MCLDUMP2", true);......error throwing that object reference is not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net

> gridExport2.WriteXlsxToResponse("MCLDUMP2", true);......error throwing
>   that object reference is not set to an instance of an object

```
protected void btnXlsExport_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DumpId = 2;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = DataAccesClass_DCR.BSNLoadCompliance(Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text));
        bsncompliance.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        bsncompliance.DataBind();
        gridExport2.WriteXlsxToResponse("MCLDUMP2", true);    
    }
```

I am trying to export to excel, but it is throwing error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: ERROR IS:  gridExport2.WriteXlsxToResponse("MCLDUMP2", true);......error throwing that object reference is not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
protected void Btnexport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.Charset = "";
    string FileName = "excel" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
    StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
    Gridviewreport.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
    Gridviewreport.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
    Gridviewreport.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
    Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: I HAD ALREADY GIVEN THE FILENAME,WAIT I M SHARING THAT CODE ALSO

Comment: protected void btnhospitalmaster_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DumpId = 2;

        Dumpfilename = "Drmasterdump1.xls";
        //ExportToExcel(); 
    }